# Proof that measure is a random measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that we have the following measure

$$μ=\sum_{i=1}^{K}δ_{x_{i}}$$

In order to prove that it is a random measure, we have to prove that the mapping

$$μ:Ω \rightarrow M$$

is measurable, where $M$ denotes the collection of bounded measure.

That this measure is bounded, I believe is easy to prove because the max value that $\mu$ can take is N. However, how do we prove that it is measurable? I have a difficulty constructing my way of thinking.

Let $M$ have a σ-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ and that for Ω we have the σ-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, then we have to prove that for every $B\in \mathcal{M}$, $\mu^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$

Also, is my understanding of random measure correct??